# Java naming convention for a collection of items whose singular and plural are the same

Tags: java, foreach, naming

I want to make a class called Series (containing episodes and information about this TV-series)

Then I have a

```
List<Series> series;
```

If I then want to loop over this collection I would want it to look like:

```
for (Series series : series) {}
```

How should I differentiate a single item of a series and a collection of series in a good way? Is it better to name it seriesCollection perhaps?

Comment: eclipse proposes series, and also listSeries. I prefer the second form but I don't think it's that important the way you name collections as long as 1) it's homogenic in all your code, 2) it shows some form of plural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For tightly scoped variables, it is ok to just call it `s`.

`for (Series s : series) {}`

Answer (score 2):

I would name the single one in your case 'nextSeries' or 'currentSeries'

Answer (score 1):

One of the following three:

1. find a more descriptive name for your list. Maybe `seriesOfTheYear` or `channelsSeries`
2. find a more descriptive name for your series. Maybe `currentSeries`
3. if only used in extremely tight scop (like a single line or two) call the single seris just `s`

Of course you can combine the options in various ways

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the this keyword in this situation. `this.series` always refer to the class field variable.

```
for (Series series : this.series) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it’s better to look at a problem from a complete different angle.

If possible I would go for Shows / show.